# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am getting a  error to create trigger in sql developer.

Here is an error-

> Trigger TRG_UPDT_STATUS compiled

> LINE/COL  ERROR
>
> ---
>
> 8/17      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ;
> Errors: check compiler log

Here is code -

```
create or replace trigger trg_updt_status BEFORE UPDATE
ON tbl_admsn_enquiry
referencing old as old_name new as new_name
for each row when(new_name.status = 'F')
declare
    st_count integer;
    ls_st_id string;
BEGIN 
select max(substr(student_id,4,length(student_id)-3)) + 1 into st_count from tbl_student_mst;

   IF st_count < 10 then
        ls_st_id='ST000'+string(st_count)
    elseif st_count< 100 then
        ls_st_id='ST00'+string(st_count)
    elseif st_count < 1000 then
        ls_st_id='ST0'+string(st_count)
    elseif st_count >= 1000 then
        ls_st_id='ST'+string(st_count) 
    end if;

    INSERT INTO tbl_student_mst (
        student_id,
        first_name,
        last_name,
        father_name,
        mother_name,
        father_occup_id,
        mother_occup_id,
        date_of_birth,
        previous_school,
        previous_class,
        current_class,
        previous_result,
        status,
        phone1,
        phone2,
        email_id,
        reg_no
    ) VALUES (
        ls_st_id,
        old_name.first_name,
        old_name.last_name,
        old_name.father_name,
        old_name.mother_name,
        old_name.father_occup_id,
        old_name.mother_occup_id,
        old_name.date_of_birth,
        old_name.previous_school,
        old_name.previous_class,
        old_name.current_class,
        old_name.previous_result,
        'A',
        old_name.phone1,
        old_name.phone2,
        old_name.email_id,
       concat(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY'),st_count)
    );
end;
```

Comment: Try using `:=` instead of `=`. ls_st_id **:=** 'ST'+string(st_count)

Comment: Getting  this ErrorTrigger  TRG_UPDT_STATUS compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
9/5       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSEIF" when expecting one of the following:     . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || member submultiset 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: Use `ELSIF` instead of `ELSEIF`. Also use semicolons after the assignments: `ls_st_id := 'ST000'+string(st_count);`

Comment: [*To assign the value of an expression to a variable, use this form of the assignment statement: `variable_name := expression;`*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-language-fundamentals.html#GUID-B91BEA99-974B-4CE7-8B28-A5B78A6918F7)

Answer (score 3):

The syntax in your IF statement isn't valid PL/SQL as mentioned in the comments below your question.. Try changing that to:

```
IF st_count < 10 THEN
   ls_st_id:='ST000'+to_char(st_count);
ELSIF st_count< 100 THEN
   ls_st_id:='ST00'+to_char(st_count);
ELSIF st_count < 1000 THEN
   ls_st_id:='ST0'+to_char(st_count);
ELSIF st_count >= 1000 THEN
   ls_st_id:='ST'+to_char(st_count);
END IF;
```

Comment: Getting this error Trigger - TRG_UPDT_STATUS compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/14      PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
8/4       PL/SQL: Statement ignored
8/24      PLS-00222: no function with name 'STRING' exists in this scope
10/4      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
10/23     PLS-00222: no function with name 'STRING' exists in this scope
12/4     ""
12/22    ""
14/4     ""
14/21     ""
17/5      ""
51/18     PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: Use a correct plsql function to cast to string. Like to_char()

Comment: 3/14      PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)
17/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
51/18     PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: getting above error

Comment: You declared ls_st_id incorrectly as `ls_st_id string;` Try something like `varchar2(20)`. Please look into PL/SQL documentation about syntax and data types.

Comment: 17/5      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
51/18     PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: getting above error

Comment: @MAYANKCHAUHAN Your question is answered. The `=` symbol mentioned in the error message should have been the assignment operator `:=` (as mentioned in the error message). Additionally, the concatenation operator is `||` not `+`, there is no function named `string()`, `varchar2` variable declarations need a length and `old_name` should be `:old_name`.